Is it that 'of' plus the words after it modifies what is before it or that the words after 'of' is modified by what is before it?
I have looked at the word of and the words coming after it as a whole that modifies the words before it. For example, I think friend in 'a friend of mine' is the head, so is piece in 'a piece of paper'. So I look at parts like 'of paper' as secondary.
However, when I was taught English at school, our teacher asked us to memorise 'a cup of...' 'a piece of/pieces of', etc., so it seemed to me that 'a cup of' is a whole that modifies the words after it, which I'm not sure is correct.
In another example There's heaps of time before the plane leaves, I noticed that the verb (is) is singular, which contradicts the first analysis. Time in this sentence seems to be the head. Is it because words like heap(s) and lot(s) are special? And how to look at phrases that contain of?

Two unrelated questions here. "A piece" and "of paper" work together, but it's simplest to say that "of paper" modifes its noun "paper."

In "There's heaps of time," there is not singular or plural, but a placeholder. And heaps of time is an expression for a very long time, but not for a pile of time here and more piles there - the length of time is one unit...singular. Heaps of time is a long time.

@YosefBaskin The role of there and the meaning of heap were clear to me. What I wasn't sure is the roles of the words that come before and after of. Since both heaps of time and lots of time take a singular verb, it seems to me heaps of and lots of are acting like adjectives.

Heaps of time works like a unit, you're right. But grammar says "of time" is less important. It modifies "heaps" and does not take charge. In a recipe, you can't add  "a cup of" without knowing a cup of what. But my mother used to substitite a cup of juice for a cup of milk in a cake, so the measure must be more important than a cup of what.

@YosefBaskin From the perspective of giving information, 'of milk' might not necessarily be less important than '(a) cup', but it seems that grammatically cup is the head (in the sense of an immediate constituent). But I only have so much knowledge of English grammar and don't know exactly what role the preposition of usually plays in a phrase. And your examples didn't help to solve my puzzle.

You must forgive me.

@YosefBaskin That's okay. I'm glad there are people viewing and commenting on my first question here.

'A cup of water' is vastly different on reasonable analysis than 'rivers of blood' or  'a case of mistaken identity'.

a cup of water / a metre of rope / a shedload of problems / a lot of fuss ... use measure (where accurate), or pseudopartitive (where approximate / woolly)  constructions with quantifiers, to show quantity of the referent of the complement of 'of'. Sometimes, [container + contents] is meant rather than a purely measure/quantitative reference: a box of chocolates / a bottle of Merlot // a yard of ale.

a crown of thorns / a house of cards / a case of mistaken identity ... use the of-phrase to specify what is being talked about, to specify what type of crown, house, case is intended. What it consists of.

The of-phrase in examples like this book of John's / that painting of Titian's ... specify ownership or authorship, specifically the owner/author. An extended usage of 'ownership' is seen in examples such as 'the Fourth of July'.

The Lord of the Isles / Professor of English Literature ... again speak of an ownership/authority/jurisdiction, but this time the domain is specified by the of-phrase.


There are doubtless other usages of of-phrases; prepositions are notoriously polysemous.

Theres's no single way to parse these phrases, it depends on the context.
When you have "A cup of coffee" versus "A cup of tea", "of tea" and "of coffee" modify "cup": they, clarify what's in the cup.
But when you have "A cup of milk" versus "A pint of milk", "cup of" and "pint of" modify "milk": they state the amount of milk.
